# Using a jQuery variable inside an SQL statement/query

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using the map-area tag inside my `index.php`, so with jQuery I am passing the ID of the clicked area tag into my Modal input value.

After filling the Modal inputs I send the values to my DB table using Ajax, and till now everything works perfectly.

HTML:

Input inside Modal looks like this:

```
<input name="Raum" id="Raum" type="text" class="form-control"> </input>
```

My Ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#btn_submit").on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var id = $("#id_input" ).val();
       var parentId = $("#Raum").val();
       var dose = $("#Dose" ).val();

       $.ajax({
          method: "post",
          url: "insert.php",
          data: {platz: id, raum: parentId, dose: dose},
          dataType: "text",
          success: function(strMessage) {

             $('#message').show(50).html("Success!");
             setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.reload(1);
             }, 1500);
          }
       });          
   });  
});
```

I am trying to use the jQuery variable where I stored the ID of the area tag in an SQL statement to be able to fetch the data according to the ID of the area.

I am trying to store the jQuery variable inside a PHP variable `$id_of_input`:

```
$id_of_input = $_POST["platz"];
```

So my SQL statement should look like this:

```
$sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT RaumNr, Platznummer, Dosennummer  FROM 

tcw_osi_raumplan_mitarbeiter WHERE Platznummer = '$id_of_input' ");

echo $id_of_input;
```

But it fails to store the jQuery variable inside `$id_of_input`.

Anyone kind or smart enough to figure it out for me? Would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Change the dataType in your ajax request to JSON instead of Text, because you are not passing a text. Then change this line `$id_of_input = $_POST["test"];`
to `$id_of_input = $_POST["platz"];` then it should be stored correctly

Comment: @weletonne dataType has nothing to do with SENDING data, its to deal with the return data (which his return is a simple echo of text). Your note about 'test' is correct though and probably the issue.

Comment: @weletonne $id_of_input = $_POST["platz"]; still is not the solution, i've already tried that before.

Comment: @IncredibleHat oh yes, TIL thanks

Comment: @Sufian please provide the html portion dealing with the elements of those ids. Also check your developers console in your web browser for any possible errors (the js is fine, but there may be some other error going on, maybe a 500, or something). Check both the console tab and network tab. Wouldn't hurt to toss in some `console.log( id, parentId, dose );` in the javascript too to see if they have data before ajax.

Comment: (as a side note... that isn't how you use `prepare` with PDO... might want to look into that after you get things working)

Comment: @IncredibleHat i have edited my code to show the HTML, also please ignore the pdo code that i provided, because i just didn't copy the whole code to make my question shorter.

Comment: How does it fail? Also are we talking about `Raum` or `Platz` as the html talks about one and the php talks about the other.

Comment: @Deckerz there are other input fields with the name and id of id_input and Dose

Comment: We may need the 'full form' you are trying to submit. Remember "ID" must be unique across the entire DOM, and also if you are not adding a field to the data sent, then it wont be automatically included. What you have shown, you are only sending three POST vars of `{platz: id, raum: parentId, dose: dose}`... so those will be the only ones you have access too in PHP. The question is wether JS is passing the RIGHT values, or if PHP just isn't getting what its given (which I doubt unless you have some php code somewhere that is blowing out your $_POST superglobal).

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file, you need to change `$_POST` Index.

```
$id_of_input = $_POST["test"];
```

to

```
$id_of_input = $_POST["raum"];
```

Because in `RAUM` variable from jquery you have that form field value.

Then it will be working fine in SQL statemnt

Comment: already tried that and still didn't work.

I had another input with the name "test" this is why i put test in the $_POST to see if it works